# While consuming messages from activemq using soapui, not all messages are dequeued

Tags: jms, automated-tests, activemq-classic, soapui, consumer

I have set up a soapui project in order to test an integration application. Once I trigger the application by sending a POST request from soapui, it will convert the message and send it to the the queue in ActiveMQ. In the next step of my testcase, I am connecting to the queue and consuming the JMS message as a rest service by using the below link

```
http://localhost:8161/api/message/test?type=queue&clientId=soapui
```

This is working fine in normal scenario but when i run a load test I see that some of the message are not consumed and it fails at the message content assertion steps.

During my investigation, I came to think that it might be related to a delay between the application sending the message to activemq and soapui trying to consume it. I tried using time delay and timeout but neither seems to work.

How could i fix this issue? Please recommend a solution.